# How to unmount oracle database?

Tags: oracle, shutdown

According to the oracle docs, during shutdown, 3 steps are performed:

Close the database.

Unmount the database.

Shut down the instance.

Is it possible to make only first 2 steps?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

```
SQL> alter database close;

Database altered.

SQL> select open_mode from v$database;

OPEN_MODE
--------------------
MOUNTED

SQL> alter database dismount;

Database altered.

SQL> select open_mode from v$database;
select open_mode from v$database
                      *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01507: database not mounted
```